# Effective constants in Baker's bound on approximations of log(3)

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, transcendental-numbers

Alan Baker gives an upper bound on $1/\log(3) - p/q$, providing a limit on how well $\log(3)$ can be approximated by $(p,q)$ of a given size.  His bound is $3^p c / q^d$.  The constants $c$ and $d$ are effective, but I can't find actual values of $c$ and $d$ for which the bound provably holds. Does anyone know such values, ideally the tightest ones so proven?  Thanks very much.

Comment: These effective but not explicit constants are always a pain. And when they are produced, they are often so large as to be effectively useless.

Comment: "Alan Baker gives..." : could you provide a reference ?

Comment: @JeanMarie  

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/hilberts-seventh-problem-and-powers-of-2-and-3/

Baker, Alan (1966), "Linear forms in the logarithms of algebraic numbers. I", Mathematika. A Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics, 13: 204–216, doi:10.1112/S0025579300003971.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but Baker provides a lower bound, rather than upper, and the one you mention is for $|3^p-2^q|$, not for $1/\log(3)-p/q$. A bound for  linear forms in two logarithms, like that of Laurent, Mignotte and Nesterenko will, without much work, give you explicit values for the constants $c$ and $d$.

Comment: @MikeBennett Thank you, my error in writing the question. Right: upper bounding the difference of powers is the same problem as lower bounding the log approximation, modulo 10 lines of algebraic manipulation.